# How to properly encode/decode diacritics sent through POST

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

Here's my problem that has been giving me a headache for a while. I need my web application to properly handle any eastern european diacritics (mostly ă Ă î Î ş Ş ţ Ţ â Â). The database handles them properly, and the php scripts handle them properly (all php scripts use utf-8 encoding), however there is a problem when handling forms.

For example, insert the following to the database, it's handled correctly, characters are encoded properly, saved properly, displayed properly:

```
$insert_value = htmlentities('ă Ă î Î ş Ş ţ Ţ â Â',ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
```

If, however, I type the same string in a text/textarea input and use POST to send it:

```
$insert_value = htmlentities($_POST['test_string'],ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
```

this will return an empty string.

I checked the the POST that the script is receiving with Firefox and instead of the 'ş Ş ţ Ţ' characters I get weird symbols(º ª þ Þ), so I'm guessing that's why htmlentities is returning empty.

I tried setting enctype on the form to multipart/form-data and it seems to send it properly but then applying htmlentities to it still somehow screws it up (for example if `$_POST['ta'] = ăĂîÎşŞţŢâÂ, htmlentities($_POST['ta'],ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8") returns $kappa;`)

**Edit**: many thanks to deceze, that link helped me handle the encoding for my web application without any htmlentities calls. I recommend that article to anyone having trouble with juggling diacritics between php, html, and databases.

Comment: Don't HTML-encode data that goes into the database, [Handle Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: uhm, thanks. Seems accept-charset="utf-8" on the form fixed it. I'll have to read trough it more after my lunch break to find a solution for inputs that aren't inside a form.

Comment: Thanks again deceze, If you want to create a short answer with that just for the sake of marking the question as answered, i'd apreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Glad the comment helped...</sub>

Don't HTML-encode data that goes into the database, [Handle Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback). There are a number of gotchas for doing that, the aforelinked article goes through the biggest ones.

Comment: Thanks, now to spend an entire work day changing a whole bunch of forms and ajax requests.