# how to convert the word "Financi�le" to "Financiële" in php

Tags: php

I Have to echo a statement which contains the word "Financi�le" , but this not the actual word i need..

I need "Financiële"

please help me how to get this word in php....

Comment: How are you 'reading' the statement in your program? Are you specifying a charset that supports BMP, such as UTF8?

Comment: Show us what's the code you use.

Comment: Please search and research - see how to ask. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14955523/how-to-properly-encode-decode-diacritics-sent-trough-post

Comment: while fetching data from db you facing this issue right?

Comment: Make sure you set HTML meta to UTF-8 as well as database.

Comment: @Ramon Bakker, thanks alot, i got the correct word when i printed it
But 1 question can i use this word in e-mails to get the actual word in want ??

Comment: See my posted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In editor, change encoding to UTF-8, add to your html:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

And update the statement source to contain the correct format - "Financial" and use the UTF-8 Encoding/Collation. For MySQL, see [How to change the default collation of a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906585/how-to-change-the-default-collation-of-a-database) here on Stack Overflow.

That should solve your problem.

Comment: i my editer
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
is using...

Comment: Change it to <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>. The goal is to make it use UTF-8 instead of the iso locale (iso-8859-1 in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
Financi&euml;ple
```

**Answer on comment**

Yes, you can, if you set a header to

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n
```

Extra information on sending email with PHP and HTML/style format:

https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/